# How to create one tableview from several Realm models?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

i have several Realm models, they look like this.

```
class Dates: Object {
dynamic var date = NSDate()
let people = List<PEOPLE>()
let animals = List<ANIMALS>()
let objects = List<OBJECTS>() }
```

Is it possible to create single tableview for specific date with corresponding sections for each model (people, animals, objects)? Any ideas how the code can look like?

It may look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is possible.

- Create a UITableViewController
- Implement the delegate methods

like that:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) ->     Int {
   return 3
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if section == 0 {
   return NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE
} else if section == 1 {
   return NUMBER_OF_ANIMALS
}else if section == 2 {
   return NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
   if section == 0 {
     return "people"
   } else if section == 1 {
     return "animals"
   }else if section == 2 {
     return "objects"
   }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

 if indexPath.section == 0 {
   cell.textLabel.text = people[indexPath.row]
 } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
   cell.textLabel.text = animals[indexPath.row]
 }else if indexPath.section == 2 {
   cell.textLabel.text = objects[indexPath.row]
 }

 return cell
}
```

Comment: great reply! it works thank you!! the only things i have to change were adding (return 1) and (return " ") in numberOfRowsInSection and titleForHeaderInSection correspondingly.

Comment: Oh sure.. I have forgotten the default returns in those functions, since I was writing it directly here.